# Class Type Factory in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there any way to create a Class Type factory?

My Code currently looks something like this (oversimplified):

```
var blah: BaseObject? //has function "setup()"
switch(objectType) {
    case .one
        blah = Object1() //inherits BaseObject overrides "setup()" 
    case .two 
        blah = Object2() //inherits BaseObject overrides "setup()""
    ...
}
blah?.setup()
```

However, I wonder if I can change it to something like this?

```
let blah: getClassType(from: objectType) = BaseObjectBuilder.create() 
// uses something like: static func create<T: BaseObject>() -> T
```

"setup()" would be moved to the create() method

This part seems to be the killer: getClassType(objectType)

Being able to define a class type based on some parameter? If this isn't possible, does anyone have a different suggestion to clean this up?

Comment: Because compiler must already know about variable type when compiling, I believe, you can't define dynamic type in this way

Comment: You could do something like `let blah: BaseObject? = getClastType(...).init()`, though

Comment: Say you could do this; what could you do with `blah`? What methods would it have available? If you only can use the methods on `BaseObject`, then just make `blah` of type `BaseObject`. If you want to use some other methods, how would you know that what you have would handle those methods? The only want do deal with this is to say what type `blah` is at compile-time; either `BaseObject` or something else. (If you have a more concrete example of your problem, there is likely a generic solution; the confusion is how abstract this example is.)

Comment: Yeah, seems like I was just overthinking this solution and it's not possible the way I had in mind. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I can't quite grasp what you're after, but the usual factory pattern seems very clean to me:

```
class BaseObject {
    func setup() { print("base object setup") }
    required init() {}
    static func factory() -> Self {
        let obj = self.init()
        obj.setup()
        return obj
    }
}
class Object1 : BaseObject {
    override func setup() { print("object1 setup") }
}
class Object2 : BaseObject {
    override func setup() { print("object2 setup") }
}
```

This works because Self is polymorphic. Here's an example, showing it does the right thing:

```
// I want a new Object1
let obj1 = Object1.factory()
// obj1 is typed as Object1, and "object1 setup" was printed
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really what you are looking for, but a common pattern that would simplify your callsite code is to move the dispatching logic into an extension on your `ObjectType` enum:

```
extension ObjectType {
  func build() -> BaseObject {
    switch self {
    case .one: return Object1()
    case .two: return Object2()
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can create a concrete object simply with

```
let blah = objectType.build()
blah.setup()
```